# stacked Column chart with line chart ApexCharts

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts, react-apexcharts

I created an `ApexChart` which will display a mixed chart (line and column) chart.
Below is the expected output.
[image]

The dummy series I am using is as follows:

```
 const chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'Desktops',
          type: 'line',
          data: [10, 41, 35, 51, 49, 62, 69, 91, 34],
        },
        {
          type: 'bar',
          name: 'Positive',
          data: [53, 40, 30, 50, 52, 60, 70, 53, 43],
        },
        {
          type: 'bar',
          name: 'Negative',
          data: [10, 20, 50, 40, 10, 10, 10, 10, 17],
        },
        {
          type: 'bar',
          name: 'Mixed',
          data: [21, 10, 10, 10, 21, 10, 10, 21, 20],
        },
        {
          type: 'bar',
          name: 'Neutral',
          data: [17, 30, 10, 0, 17, 20, 10, 17, 20],
        },
      ],
      chart: {
        stacked: true,
        toolbar: {
          show: false,
        },
        animations: {
          enabled: false,
          animateGradually: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          dynamicAnimation: {
            enabled: false,
          },
        },
        zoom: {
          enabled: false,
        },
      },
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },

      markers: {
        size: 4,
      },
      colors: ['#000000', '#29A380', '#FF9B2B', '#C95A56', '#707070'],
      legend: { show: false },
      xaxis: {
        categories: [
          'Jan',
          'Feb',
          'Mar',
          'Apr',
          'May',
          'Jun',
          'Jul',
          'Aug',
          'Sep',
        ],
        tooltip: {
          enabled: true,
        },
        axisBorder: {
          show: false,
        },
      },

      grid: {
        show: true,
        borderColor: '#DCDCDC',
        strokeDashArray: 2,
        position: 'back',
      },
      stroke: {
        curve: 'smooth',
        colors: ['#15506E'], // Customize the graph line color
        width: 2, // Customize the graph line width
      },
    };
```

When I use this series I get following issues:

- labels on y-axis goes upto 200 but max value in series is 91. if I remove either `type:line` series or `type:bar` then labels on y-axis snap back to 100.

[image]

- When I use `stackType:'100%'`, which is mentioned in documentation. labels on x and y axis does not show up and half of the chart cuts.

[image]

- I don't want borders which are visible in stacked column.

How can I achieve the expected graph which I have posted above? can I use both line and stacked column chart together?
I am using `ApexChart v3.43.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have achieved expected result by using [multiple Y-Axis](https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/multiple-yaxis-scales/). Set min and max for bar graphs from 0 to 100 and for line graph set it to -100 to 100.

A dirty way is to stack two separate Apex chart instances using different Z-indexes and setting position to absolute. but again thats not recommended.